# javascript/highchart append value to an existing series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highchart that potentially receives data with duplicate keys, I was wondering how I can build some logic that'll merge the two key/values together into one series.

This is my data

```
var dataArray = [{
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-07",
 Brand: "Toyota",
 Count: 3
}, {
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-02",
 Brand: "Ford",
 Count: 258
}, {
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-03",
 Brand: "Ford",
 Count: 239
}, {
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-04",
 Brand: "Ford",
 Count: 197
}, {
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-05",
 Brand: "Ford",
 Count: 187
}, {
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-06",
 Brand: "Ford",
 Count: 418
}, {
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-07",
 Brand: "Ford",
 Count: 344
}, {
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-03",
 Brand: "Mercedes",
 Count: 43
}, {
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-04",
 Brand: "Mercedes",
 Count: 220
}, {
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-03",
 Brand: "Chrysler",
 Count: 3
}, {
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-04",
 Brand: "Chrysler",
 Count: 3
}, {
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-06",
 Brand: "Chrysler",
 Count: 6
}, {
 ErrorDate: "2017-09-07",
 Brand: "Chrysler",
 Count: 1
}];
```

I have to keys with 'Ford' and 'ford' and what I want to accomplish is to merge those two and append there values under one series.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pvbtmx2j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/tLd9711z/2/

```
var dataArray = [{
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-07",
  Brand: "Toyota",
  Count: 3
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-02",
  Brand: "Ford",
  Count: 258
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-03",
  Brand: "Ford",
  Count: 239
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-04",
  Brand: "Ford",
  Count: 197
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-05",
  Brand: "Ford",
  Count: 187
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-06",
  Brand: "Ford",
  Count: 418
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-07",
  Brand: "Ford",
  Count: 344
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-03",
  Brand: "Mercedes",
  Count: 43
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-04",
  Brand: "Mercedes",
  Count: 220
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-03",
  Brand: "Chrysler",
  Count: 3
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-04",
  Brand: "Chrysler",
  Count: 3
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-06",
  Brand: "Chrysler",
  Count: 6
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-07",
  Brand: "Chrysler",
  Count: 1
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-04",
  Brand: "ford",
  Count: 22
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-06",
  Brand: "ford",
  Count: 25
}, {
  ErrorDate: "2017-09-07",
  Brand: "ford",
  Count: 63
}].reduce((prevVal, currVal, index) => {
  currVal.Brand = currVal.Brand.replace(/\b\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase());
  prevVal.push(currVal);
  return prevVal;
}, []);
```

If you want to merge it further by date - you will need to modify reduce function, and chose higher value or smaller value or add one to another.